# How to pin two buttons below toolbar while scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview

[image]

I want to achieve something like this as shown in image

I have tried this code but not able to pin button below top image or toolbar

In this I am trying to have toolbar and below that i have nested scrollview and inside that scrollview I have one more scrollview(scrollview2).

I want to pin or anchor a button to scrollview2 and when i scroll this scrollview2 up then i want button to pin to toolbar

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">



    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/homescrn_logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrlview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"></LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hi I am here"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/scrlview"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center|bottom" />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"
                android:background="@drawable/restaurant" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_business_profilescrn_business_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:text="Chillis Kuwait"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_business_profilescrn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_business_profilescrn_business_name"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_business_profilescrn_type"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingRight="40dp"
                        android:text="Restaurent"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_business_profilescrn_type"
                        android:background="#4989f2">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:paddingRight="5dp"
                            android:text="Open"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:background="#db4437"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_ratings"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:text="4.5"
                            android:textColor="#fff" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_business_profilescrn"
                    android:background="#db4437"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:paddingLeft="20dp">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/ll_followers"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                                    android:text="243"
                                    android:textColor="#fff"
                                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_business_profile_folowers"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Followers"
                                    android:textColor="#fff"
                                    android:textSize="20sp" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="1dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                android:background="#fff" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                                    android:text="243"
                                    android:textColor="#fff"
                                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Likes"
                                    android:textColor="#fff"
                                    android:textSize="20sp" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="1dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                android:background="#fff" />
                        </LinearLayout>


                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:paddingRight="16dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="right"
                                android:text="243"
                                android:textColor="#fff"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Views"
                                android:textColor="#fff"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>


                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_business_profilescrn_top_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_back_300wt" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_share_300wt" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_share_300wt" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#db4437"
                android:text="Local Feed" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#db4437"
                android:text="My Feed" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

this is what exactly i want to achieve.

I have a collapsing toolbar which I want to scroll half and I am able to achieve that.

Further I have two buttons in nested scrollview which i want to pin to toolbar when I scrolldown as shown in gif.

Comment: I am already using Co-ordinator layout in my xml code. please check.

Comment: Follow this link may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780591/making-a-middle-element-to-get-stuck-in-the-header-scrollview-listview

Comment: @MohitGoel Try with my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest taking advantage of the `CoordinatorLayout` by putting the content above the tabs inside a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. And using a `TabLayout` instead of two `Buttons`, which should be more in line with the Android design guidelines (though you could just swap the `TabLayout` for a `LinearLayout` with two buttons if your prefer):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarlayout android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/toolbar_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <!-- YOUR SCROLLING TOOLBAR CONTENT HERE -->

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:backgroud="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:menu="@menu/tabs_main"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- YOUR MAIN SCROLLING CONTENT HERE -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Notice that the `TabLayout` is outside of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, but still inside of the `AppBarLayout`. This will keep the `TabLayout` pinned underneath the `Toolbar` and whatever content you put inside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. And no need for multiple `NestedScrollView` layouts.

There may be some problems with the spacing of the `LinearLayout` (some content may be hidden under the `Toolbar`), but if that is the case, you should be able to set the top margin of the `LinearLayout` to `?attr/actionBarSize`. I haven't tested any of this, so comment if you run into issues.

---

You can even swap out the `NestedScrollView` for a `ViewPager` (make sure you keep the `app:layout_behavior` though). This would allow you to easily tie the tabs to two fragments using `mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager)`.

---

**EDIT** After testing, unfortunately this does not seem to work the way I had hoped. The problem is that part of the content is hidden underneath the `Toolbar`, even if you set the top margin to `?attr/actionBarSize`. This is because, for some reason, the height of the status bar is not included in the top margin of the layout. You *could* try to guess what the top margin *should* be, but this can lead to unexpected padding between the toolbar and the content.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. 
I am trying to add an imageview in toolbar. Even though I am giving its width as match parent, its still giving some padding to imageview.

Comment: @MohitGoel Huh, that is strange. Post your new layout? Maybe I'll see something you missed.

Comment: Is there any another way to do this thing?

Comment: @MohitGoel There are definitely other ways of doing it, they are just more complex. You can always create your own `ViewGroup`, that intercepts touch events, and handles them the way you want. This just seemed like the easiest solution that Android provides, though it is more meant for just putting an image behind the toolbar, not a whole layout.

Comment: @MohitGoel Actually, is that the only functionality you are looking to achieve? I noticed in your first comment you stated you tried putting an `ImageView` in the toolbar, which is not exactly what your initial GIF shows, but that *is* what the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is meant for. The extra padding around an `ImageView` could be due to the `scaleType`, though I would have to know more to be sure.

Comment: Please check my new xml file and requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Set an id to your LinearLayout:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:@"+id/my_linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
```

And after that  create your buttons below your linear layout, to align them:

```
        <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:text="My Button 1"
        android:id="@+id/mesa_btn_salva"

        android:layout_below="@+id/my_linear_layout" />
```

All of that inside your ScroolView.

And that's all.

Comment: NestedScrollView can have only one child. And aslo if i simply add button below linear layout it will not pin below NestedScrollView  and toolbar after scrolling.

Comment: Thats true, I forgot.
So create one Relative View and put your Linear Layout (my_linear_layout) inside    and the button.