# Pin collapsingtoolbar child

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

```
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
```

This attribute seems to only work if the view is a toolbar and won't work on other views such as relativelayout, why?

Comment: check this ans it will sure help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794409/how-to-pin-two-buttons-below-toolbar-while-scrolling

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pin two buttons below toolbar while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794409/how-to-pin-two-buttons-below-toolbar-while-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

`app:layout_collapseMode= "pin"`

- pin is set to this mode, the `Toolbar` can remain on the screen when the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is fully shrunk.
- Fixed mode, finally fixed at the top of the fold

Because it was `CollapsingToolbarLayout`'s attribute .

And it also used in `CoordinatorLayout` .